# navigating from detail view controller to table view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, detailview

i am facing a situation that i am loading data correctly to a uitableviewcontroller. also i am loading data correctly to the detail view controller.

what i am using:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowPaymentDetails"])
    {
        DetailPaymentViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.paymentsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        detailViewController.payment = [arrayOfPayment objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]];
    }
}
```

the problem i have is that when i am going back (through normal drag and drop swipe) the uitableviewcontroller is reloaded. since this takes data from a web service ... i don't want to reload the data.

Can you help me on any ideas on this.

Thnx in advance.

Comment: Remove webservice calling functionality from viewdidappear and put that code in viewdidload..

Comment: it is already at the viewdidload method

Comment: Once use -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath to push to detail view instead of -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender method!!

Comment: i am comfortable with the segue solution. the problem i have is from the opposite side, from detail view to list view. ... is this change going to fix this problem ?

Comment: I had this problem too, i think you make a push from viewA to viewB and then push from viewB to viewA. So the problem is you push 2 times instead of push and then pop. You have to use the pop equivalent to prepareForSegue: You can check if you push 2 times, when you nslog the viewDidLoad.

Comment: @shivam has the right idea. I'm fairly certain the only way to keep the data in the table when you return is to use the built in method for selecting a UITableViewCell...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your segueing to the TableViewController from the DetailViewController. I think your creating a new TableViewController and not going back to the original one. You can check this in the debugger by setting a breakpoint in viewWillApear and looking at the value of self.

```
(lldb) po self
$0 = 0x1ddd2480
```

You should do this in your DetailViewController to go back to the TableViewController.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```